# Disabling the toolbar?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to disable the toolbar via a link in my HTML. I've tried:

```
<a href="window.open(URL, '', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no...')">Click</a>
```

But it is not working. Could somebody provide some direction here?

I would prefer to not use Javascript.

Comment: Which toolbar? Or do you mean the status bar, which would allow you to hide the true address of a link?

Comment: You don't want to use javascript but you paste javascript code? I don't get it?

Comment: toolbar i.e address bar, file menus and so on......

Comment: @user254582: You can't do that without javascript.

Comment: hey can we cal a java script function from html?? wil it work??

Comment: Please don't do this. Pop-ups without chrome are bad for usability and can be bad for security. Even *with* JavaScript, browsers are cracking down on this ability.

Answer (score 1):

I think could be no possible for security reasons, but you can open the new window
and then

```
window.opener = self;
window.close();
```

but this will work unless client (browser) security is set to very low.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without the use of JavaScript and it is also not possible without opening the target page in a new window.

Something like this will work if you want to open the page in a new window and JavaScript is acceptable:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('example.html', '', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no')">Click</a>
```

Comment: hey can we cal a java script function from html?? wil it work??